# saving button state in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a few custom jquery buttons with `datatables` to do some sorting. Unfortunately when I leave the page and come back, `datatables` remembers its state, but the toggle button doesnt. So I am trying to set a cookie when the button is toggled so I can read it later, but I cant seem to get it working.

Here is my button code with the cookie creation:

```
$('#completed_button').bind('change', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Hide Completed');
    oTable.fnFilter('Completed',6,false);
    $.cookie('showCompletedState', 'checked');
  } else {
    $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Show Completed');
    oTable.fnFilter('',6,false);
    $.cookie('showCompletedState', 'unchecked');
  }
});
```

Now here is my attempt at reading the cookie and setting the button state:

```
var showCompletedState = $.cookie('showCompletedState');
if (showCompletedState == 'checked') {
    <-- need something here to actually change button state -->
    $('#completed_button').button('option', 'label', 'Hide Completed');
    oTable.fnFilter('Completed',6,false);
} else if (showCompletedState == 'unchecked') {
    <-- need something here to actually change button state -->
    $('#completed_button').button('option', 'label', 'Show Completed');
    oTable.fnFilter('',6,false);        
}
```

Comment: How about changing its attribute? Such as: $(#button).attr('checked':'checked');

Comment: Dave, you were really close, it came out to be `$("#completed_button").prop("checked", true);` I guess attr is deprecated since 1.6

Comment: Cool, Im glad it helps a little bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Dave's suggestion, answer turned out to be `$("#completed_button").prop("checked", true);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i completely understand, but if you just want the button to look as if it has a different state. Why not assign a CSS style for different states?

Comment: Sean,
I didnt want to just change the visual state of the button, I wanted to change its actual state. The jquery toggle is an extension of checkbox.